# ReadmoreJS - CodePen does not output anything

Tags: javascript

I was reading upon [ReadmoreJS](https://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) and I was thrilled to give it a try on CodePen. However, when I read the instructions on the website and implemented some code on CodePen, it doesn't work at all. Here is a link to my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/NeroSonic/pen/pGpObO) to view the code. In the JS tab, I made sure to include *jQuery* as the first script and *ReadmoreJS* as a dependency.

Here is some code snippets from my CodePen:

> HTML

```
<article>Lorem ipsum and all that jazz...</article>
```

> Javascript

```
$('article').readmore();
```

As you can see, I'm targeting every `article` tag, but it doesn't seem to be working. There are also no console errors. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the default collapsed height set by the plugin is 200px: and in your CodePen example, the height of the `<article>` does not exceed that, so you do not see the readmore plugin kicking into action.

You can either [set the `collapsedHeight` to something shorter than 200px](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvpGZX), use a longer piece of text, or narrow the width of the `<article>` element to see the plugin work.

Also, you might want to add `article { overflow: hidden; }` to your stylesheet to make sure the excess content gets nicely tucked out of the way.